# Can I make a new get/post request upon timeout error using axios?

Tags: javascript, node.js, axios

Having tried to pull data using get/post request using axios, I have faced some timeout errors.
Could anyone let me know if there is any way I can make another get/post request in catch block?

I'm using nodejs only to do somethings for my back-end. (not using React or anything else)

Say, what I would like to implement is something like the below.

```
try {
    let data = await axios.get(url) 
    return data
} catch(e) {
    if (e.errortype == 'timeout') 
    make another await axios.get(url) and repeat this till it gives an appropriate response 
}
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: you could implement a recursive function

Answer (score 1):

Couldn't you just create your request within a function and call it again on failure?

```
const request = async () => {
  try {
    const url = "https://someurl.com/";
    let data = await axios.get(url);
    return data;
  } catch (e) {
    if (e.errortype == "timeout") {
      request();
    }
  }
};
```

Comment: You're not using await for request() call and you're not returning request() call response.